# TSV: how to concatenate field 2s if field 1 is duplicate

Tags: bash, awk, sed, scripting, csv

I'm building a Swedish-English sentence deck for ANKI from the Creative Common licensed content of tatoeba.org.

Please help me turning sample 1 to sample 2 (preferably in bash):

```
#sample1
a 1
a 2
b 3
c 4
c 5

#sample2
a 1<br>2
b 3
c 4<br>5
```

Duplicates in field 1 are always subsequent.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry it seems I was not specific enough. This is a TSV, fields are separated by tabs.

Nonetheless using your input I will be able to solve it. Thank you all!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk 'p==$1{printf "<br>%s", $2;next}{if(p){print ""};p=$1;printf "%s", $0}END{print ""}' file
a 1<br>2
b 3
c 4<br>5
```

Comment: @NyitraiLőrinc You should not need  `-F'\t\` since with no `FS` it uses any space as separator, both space and tabs.

Comment: @Jotne My actual data consists spaces and tabs, not specifying field separator resulted wrong output.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ape '$_ = ($l eq $F[0]) ? "<br>$F[1]" : "\n@F"; $l=$F[0]' file
```

Comment: @MohitJain it looks at first value in line and decides whether it should output `<br>second_val` or `\nfirst_val second_val`

Comment: Thank you. I hope this comment would be helpful for other readers as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `awk` command also,

```
awk 'BEGIN {getline; id=$1; line=$0} {if ($1 != id) {print line; line = $0; } else {line = line "<br>" $2;} id=$1;} END {print line;}' file
```

Otput:

```
a 1<br>2
b 3
c 4<br>5
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'N;s/^((\S+\s).*)\n\2/\1<br>/;P;D' file
```

Compare the current line with the subsequent line and if the keys match combine otherwise print the current line, delete it and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{if(a[$1]){a[$1]=a[$1]"<br>"$2}else{a[$1]=$1FS$2;b[i++]=$1}} END{for(i=0;i in b; i++) print a[b[i]];}' sample1
```

Output:

```
a 1<br>2
b 3
c 4<br>5
```

Creates the output in array `a`, uses array `b` to preserve the order of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `awk`

```
awk 'f!=$1 {printf (a?RS:"")$0;f=$1;a=1;next} {print "<br>"$2;f=$1;a=0}' file
a 1<br>2
b 3
c 4<br>5
```

Comment: Won't this only work if there are no more than 2 consecutive dups.

Comment: @jaypal Yes,its not asked for more.