# Comparing field#1 in two adjacent lines and printing fields#2 from all the lines where field#1 is identical

Tags: python, bash, perl, awk, sed

Can be considered a variant of  [this bash question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23719065/tsv-how-to-concatenate-field-2s-if-field-1-is-duplicate) that I looked up before asking this question here.

Following is a sample file:

```
C=b933cda8ce0/0 p=880080
C=b933cdd6580/0 p=880080
C=b933d02a240/0 p=880080
C=b933d059610/0 p=880080
C=b933d1c8690/0 p=880080
C=b933d2c1b60/0 p=1560315
C=b933d2c1b60/0 p=880080
C=b933d32f240/0 p=1229793
C=b933d32f240/0 p=123412
```

Output here should be:

```
C=b933d2c1b60/0 p1=1560315 p2=880080
C=b933d32f240/0 p1=1229793 p2=123412
```

I need to print out all the values of field#2 against field#1 from all the lines where field#1 matches.

Although I got the job done using the following long one-liner but it doesn't really seem elegant/efficient to me:

`d=0; q=0; cat file |while read -r c p; do if [[ $c = $d ]]; then printf "$c\t$p\t$q\n"; fi; d=$c; q=$p; done`

Code could be in any of the langs/tools tagged.

Comment: Are the lines with matching field one values always going to be adjacent like that?

Comment: @EtanReisner well if they aren't, I can always sort them. So, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

awk to the rescue

```
awk '{
  c[$1]++; 
  sub("p","p"c[$1],$2); 
  sep=(c[$1]>1)?FS:""; 
  a[$1]=a[$1] sep $2
} 
END {
  for(i in a) print i, a[i]
}' file
```

concatenate second fields based on the key (first field).  Suffix p with the index of the parameter (counted in c).  There is a formatting trick to not to double space the first and second fields.